# Creating a Managed Metadata column using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I have a list in SP2010, it has a managed metadata column, I need to migrate list to SP2013 and also managed metadata column should be created. I have referenced

[https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/][1]

[https://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-site-columns-content-types-app-model/][1]

I have used the below code,it does not show any error but also the column is not getting created.

```
if (field.TypeAsString == "TaxonomyFieldType")
                                {
                                    Guid termStoreId =  Guid.Empty;
                                    Guid termSetId = Guid.Empty;

                                    GetTaxonomyFieldInfo(srcContext, out termStoreId, out termSetId);  
                                    TaxonomyField taxonomyField = srcContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
                                    taxonomyField.SspId = termStoreId;
                                    taxonomyField.TermSetId = termSetId;
                                    taxonomyField.TargetTemplate = String.Empty;
                                    taxonomyField.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
                                    taxonomyField.Update();
                                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                                    string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "'/>";
                                    targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
                                    targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
                                    srcFieldCollections.Add(field);

                                }


private void GetTaxonomyFieldInfo(ClientContext clientContext, out Guid termStoreId, out Guid termSetId)
        {
            termStoreId = Guid.Empty;
            termSetId = Guid.Empty;

            TaxonomySession session = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
            TermStore termStore = session.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();

            TermSetCollection termSets = termStore.GetTermSetsByName("ABC", 1033);

            clientContext.Load(termSets, tsc => tsc.Include(ts => ts.Id));
            clientContext.Load(termStore, ts => ts.Id);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            termStoreId = termStore.Id;
            termSetId = termSets.FirstOrDefault().Id;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it as below:

```
if (field.TypeAsString == "TaxonomyFieldType")
{
    Guid termStoreId =  Guid.Empty;
    Guid termSetId = Guid.Empty;

    GetTaxonomyFieldInfo(srcContext, out termStoreId, out termSetId);  

    string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "' Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "'/>";
    targetcollField.AddFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, true, AddFieldOptions.AddToDefaultContentType);
    targetContext.Load(targetcollField);
    srcFieldCollections.Add(field);

    TaxonomyField taxonomyField = srcContext.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
    taxonomyField.SspId = termStoreId;
    taxonomyField.TermSetId = termSetId;
    taxonomyField.TargetTemplate = String.Empty;
    taxonomyField.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
    taxonomyField.Update();
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

}


private void GetTaxonomyFieldInfo(ClientContext clientContext, out Guid termStoreId, out Guid termSetId)
{
    termStoreId = Guid.Empty;
    termSetId = Guid.Empty;

    TaxonomySession session = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);
    TermStore termStore = session.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();

    TermSetCollection termSets = termStore.GetTermSetsByName("ABC", 1033);

    clientContext.Load(termSets, tsc => tsc.Include(ts => ts.Id));
    clientContext.Load(termStore, ts => ts.Id);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    termStoreId = termStore.Id;
    termSetId = termSets.FirstOrDefault().Id;
}
```

Comment: `Cannot find proxy for type with id "{981cbc68-9edc-4f8d-872f-71146fcbb84f}"` exception occurs, may be because it is SP2010

Comment: Yes, you need to enter the name of the term in the 2013 term set.

Comment: How to enter the name of the term in the 2013 term set using CSOM?

Comment: In your 2013, environment create your term in a term set. Also in your code, you need to pass the 2013 context in the `GetTaxonomyFieldInfo` method

Comment: please help me with the code

Comment: go to the term store and create a term under a term set manually. Also in the code, replace `srcContext` with the 2013 environment context.

Comment: But I should not create term store manually, as I am migrating list, it should already be there or it should be created using code..

Comment: correct, it should already be there after migration. Check if it's already present, if its there, then just change the `srcContext` to the context of 2013 environment.